# How to plot lines with angle between 0-360 degree

Tags: r, excel, ggplot2

I want to plot a time-angle series in x-y coordinates. when the difference between two neighbors is less than 180, they will be lined directly. Otherwise, one will be lined to 360 and another will be lined to 0 with the same time, it means the path crossed the 0/360 point. 
What I known is to calculate the two interpolating points first, and plot two segments, is there some smart direct way to do that?

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(time=c(1,2,3,4),angle=c(200,100,320,20))
#ggplot()+geom_line(data,aes(time,angle))
#three lines codes is expected,but now it is->
ymax=360
ymin=0
ythd=(ymax-ymin)/2 #180
j=1 #left end point number
n=nrow(data)# rignt end point number
aid=data[1,] #aids line from end point to border
gg=ggplot()
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  delta=data[i+1,2]-data[i,2]
  #divide groups
  if(abs(delta)>ythd){
    gg=gg+geom_line(data=data[j:i,],aes(time,angle))
    j=i+1
    fst=data[i,2]
    stp=data[j,1]-data[i,1]
    aid[1,]=data[i,]
    #interpolating points
    if(delta>0){
      rto=fst/(360-(delta))
      aid[2:3,1]=data[i,1]+rto*stp
      aid[2,2]=ymin
      aid[3,2]=ymax
    }else{
      rto=(360-fst)/(360+delta)
      aid[2:3,1]=data[i,1]+rto*stp
      aid[2,2]=ymax
      aid[3,2]=ymin
    }
    aid[4,]=data[j,]
    #aids line
    gg=gg+geom_line(data=aid[1:2,],aes(time,angle))   
    gg=gg+geom_line(data=aid[3:4,],aes(time,angle))   
  }

}
#the last group
gg=gg+geom_line(data=data[j:n,], aes(time,angle))
gg
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Show your code and a picture of the expected plot, please.

Comment: @TeeKea sorry，I am limited to upload pictures because of reputation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDHET.jpg

Comment: I have edited your question to include the image.

Comment: Now, please show the code you used to generate such a plot so that people can help you.

Comment: @TeeKea Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was a fun exercise. Here's what I came up with. I only tested on this one dataset so it may need some tweaking.

```
library(tidyverse)
data<-data.frame(t1=c(1,2,3,4),a1=c(200,100,300,20))

data <- data %>%
  arrange(t1) %>%
  mutate(t2 = c(data$t1[-1], 0)) %>%
  mutate(a2 = c(data$a1[-1], 0)) %>%
  mutate(grp = 0)


get_split <- function(t1, t2, a1, a2) {
  # TEST: t1=1;t2=2;a1=10;a2=355
  if((a2 - a1) > 180) {
    return(a1/(a1 + 360 - a2)*(t2 - t1) + t1)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

data <- rbind(
  data[,c('t1', 'a1', 'grp')],
  data.frame(t1 = mapply(get_split, data$t1, data$t2, data$a1, data$a2),
             a1 = 0,
             grp = 0),
  data.frame(t1 = mapply(get_split, data$t1, data$t2, data$a1, data$a2),
             a1 = 360,
             grp = 1)
)

data <- data[!is.na(data$t1),] %>%
  arrange(t1)

data$grp <- cumsum(data$grp)

ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = t1, y = a1, group = grp))
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice try. it will be better if there less codes, such as  a special parameters in ggplot function or a package with a special function.

Comment: FYI: The line from 3rd point to 4th point should be divided into two parts, not a direct line.